# How to Backup of my tables in Mysql Database using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, database-backups, mysql-backup

I'm having around 150tables in my Schema. In that few tables are master table it will be around 20 tables. Without taking the backup of other tables i want to take the backup of Master tables only and i have to achieve this through C# code.

I'm using VS2008 and MySQL

Answer (score 0):

First create a C# program to connect to server and then issue commands to get your backup.

Backup commands can be found here -

[Database Backup Methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html)